# Slow sum computation

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

I'm doing a simple OLS regression and I strikes my attention that this very simple computation takes several seconds to perform in Mathematica

```
Sum[(x[[i]] - Mean[x]) (y[[i]] - Mean[y]), {i, 1, 40}]/ Sum[(x[[i]] - Mean[x])^2, {i, 1, 40}]
```

The equivalent in Maple is instantaneous:

```
(sum((x[i]-Mean(x))*(y[i]-Mean(y)), i = 1 .. 40))/(sum((x[i]-Mean(x))^2, i = 1 .. 40))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Sum` holds its arguments, it ends up computing `Mean[x]` and `Mean[y]` in every step in the sum. Try

```
Total[(x - Mean[x])(y - Mean[y])]/Total[(x - Mean[x])^2]
```

which uses vectorized operations. In general, `Sum` is most suited to compute sums of symbolic quantities, sums with symbolic limits etc. `Total` or `Tr` is much faster for numeric stuff.